# Can I use Cassandra table name as date partitioner?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I'm struggling with a Cassandra/Spark data modeling problem. I store user data in Cassandra that is partitioned by session_id for a web session. Each day, I want to run a Spark job that analyzes the user sessions for that day. I'd like Spark to only consider the data for the current day, as when I try to run the Spark job for all of the session data (currently we store 60 days of session data in a single table), and filter for the current day, it takes a long time. The user_id partition was chosen because it is useful to also be able to query for a single user session.

To make the data as small as possible for Spark, I was thinking of creating 60 tables, each for a day for the next 60 days, and writing only to the table that corresponds to each day. For dealing with cross day sessions, I would write to both the previous day's table and the current day's table, for a window equal to the max amount of time we allot to a user session (8 minutes). I could then remove the dups in Spark. Does this sound like a sane plan? Am I using Cassandra or Spark incorrectly here?  Any advice appreciated.

Comment: what is your table schema ? Is that only contain session_id in partition key? Why don't you have combination of session_id and date as partition key ? By this way you can load only the current day data from cassandra .